# Инициализация val в data class

Tags: kotlin

У меня есть класс, который принимает одну переменную и немного обрабатывает её для дальнейшего хранения. Мне хотелось бы иметь переменную `value` неизменяемой и при этом пользоваться всеми функциями `data class` (при этом в *equals* и *hashCode* должна фигурировать только новая `value`)

```kotlin
data class GF(var value: Int = 0) {

    init {
        value = value % 10
    }
}
```

Я пытался делать так:

```kotlin
data class GF {
    val value: Int

    constructor(data: Int = 0) {
        value = data % 10
    }
}
```

Однако получаю: `Data class must have at least one primary constructor parameter`

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть что то типа: `data class GF(val value: Int = mod(field, 10)) {}` если это возможно в Kotlin

Comment: обязательно data class? а что должно быть при вызове copy метода с аргументом 10 например?

Comment: @IR42, если вручную писать все эти методы (*equals, hashCode, copy*), то теряется смысл котлина, поэтому хотелось бы оставить *data class*. При вызове *copy()* должен быть объект с `value = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте поле в конструкторе приватным и добавьте еще одно поле `value` в ваш класс:

```kotlin
data class GF(private var data: Int) {
    val value: Int

    init {
        data %= 10
        value = data
    }
}
```

Таким образом, `equals` и `hashCode` будут использовать обновленное значение. С методом `copy` тоже никаких проблем не будет.